# Conditional mass function of minimum of two discrete uniform random variables given the maximum

Tags: probability, self-study, uniform-distribution, dice

I'm revising for an upcoming exam with old assignment questions, but I got this one wrong at the time and we aren't given model solutions. Looking for advice on whether or not my second attempt for A) is correct,and if not a tip in the right direction, and any hints on part B), thank you.

**Let $X$ and $Y$ denote the respective outcomes when two fair dice are thrown. Let $U=\text{min}(X,Y)$, $V=\text{max}(X,Y)$, $S = U+V$, and $T=V-U$**

**A) Determine the conditional probability mass function for $U$ given $V=v$**

**B) Determine the joint mass function for $S$ and $T$**

My Attempt:

**A)**

$\begin{align}
P(U=u|V=v)&=P(\text{min}(X,Y)=u|\text{Max}(X,Y)=v)\\
&=[P(X=u,Y=v)+P(X=v,Y=u)]/P(\text{max}(x,y)=v)\\
&=\frac{1}{18 \times P(\text{max}(x,y)=v)}
\end{align}$

$\begin{align}
P(\text{max}(x,y)=v)&=P(X=v,Y\leq v)+P(Y=v,X\leq v)\\
&=2 \times P(X=v,Y\leq v)\quad  \text{(By symmetry)} \\
&=2\times(1/6)\times (v/6)\\
&=v/18
\end{align}$

Substituting back into the above gives the conditional distribution for $U$ given $V=v$ as $1/v$.

Edit: After revision the PMF for the maximum came out as (2v-1)/36 which means the above conditional pmf is definitely wrong

$B)$

$\begin{align}
P(S=s,T=t)&=P(U+V=s,V-U=t)\\
&=P(X+Y=s,|X-Y|=t)\\
&=P(X+Y=s,X-Y=t)+P(X+Y=s,X-Y=-t)\\
\vdots \\
&=P(Y=(s-t)/2,X=(s+t)/2)+P(X=(s-t)/2,Y=(s+t)/2)
\end{align}$
I'm stuck here. A hint in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

Draw a $6$" $\times$ $6$" square and divide it into a $6\times 6$
array of $36$ one-inch
squares. Label the rows and columns with numbers $1$-$6$ and in each square, write down the values of $(X,Y)$, $U$, $V$, $S$ and $T$ in
each square . Then,
count!

Comment: That's what I answered initially, and it got marked wrong. I just can't see a way of expressing it in an actual pmf though, unless I do it in some sort of case by case basis. Any ideas?

Comment: @Patrick Did you forget to count? If $\max(X,Y) = V$, its probability mass function is _very definitely_ not $\frac{v}{18}$ for $1 \leq v \leq 6$. Since the numerators of $\frac{v}{18}$ sum to $1+2+3+4+5+6 = 21$, the pmf that you found does _not_ satisfy the requirement $\sum_{v=1}^6 p_V(v) = 1$.

Comment: You're right, thanks for pointing that out. It just agreed with what I would expect the conditional pmf to be so I didn't bother checking. Will work on the problem again later and update it when I get something that works.

Comment: I guess a rest helped me think because just after reading your comment I got the following:


$P(max(X,Y)=v) = P(max(X,Y)<=v)-P(max(X,Y)<=v-1)$


=$P(X<=v,Y<=v)-P(X<=v-1,Y<=v-1)$


=$v^2/36 - (v-1)^2/36$


=$(2*v-1)/36$


Which does indeed sum to 1 over all possible values of v. Unless you can spot some flawed leap of logic in my reasoning when I changed the max into terms of X,Y.

Comment: Consequently this must mean the joint PMF I derived in A) to find the conditional must be wrong, as 2/(2v-1) definitely does not sum to 1 as it should for some fixed v. It occurs to me that if you had $max(X,Y)=min(X,Y)$ then clearly the probability cannot be 1/18 as there is only one instance that could happen. Again now I'm confused how to express this without doing a case by case pmf.

Comment: Sorry for the excessive comments...

 So I now realize the joint PMF should be 1/36 if $v=u$ and 2/36 if $v\neq u$. I double checked this by summing up over possible values and it did come out to 1. So this would presumably make the conditional PMF $2/(2v-1)$ if $u\neq v$ and $1/(2v-1)$ if $u=v$. This seems to also sum to 1 correctly with fixed values of v. I'm still completely lost as for part B though.

Comment: Going off of how I defined the PMF in (A) in 2 cases, I've attempted to do a similar thing using how far I got into (B) where I have expressed it in terms of the probabilities of X and Y being functions of s and t. What I got was the 3 case PMF. If either $(s-t)/2$ or $(s+t)/2$ does not belong to ${1,2,...,6}$ the probability is zero.  If both belong to ${1,2,...,6}$ and $t=0$ then the probability is $1/36$. Finally if both belong to ${1,2,...,6}$ but $t=|=0$ then the probability is $2/36$. Do you think it's possible to get anything more precise, or is this the best?